# Why Doesn't Applying Optical Flow on Image Produce Accurate Next Frame

Tags: computer-vision, opticalflow

As part of my research I wanted to see how accurate the ground truth optical flow is for interpolating the current frame to the next one. I used this method https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11068 to apply the optical flow onto the frame, and I compared it to the actual new frame.

However, the image seems obviously slightly off around the edges. I am using the Sintel dataset. Is it possible to get an accurate prediction of the next frame using the ground truth optical flow, or can it not be helped? Its just slightly off around the edges of the objects, but since it is the ground truth optical flow I was expecting it to be the same. I took the difference between the actual next frame, and the predicted next frame as well.

Original Frame
[image: Original Frame]

Visualized Ground Truth Optical Flow
[image: Visualized Optical Flow]

Actual Next Frame
[image: Actual Next Frame]

Predicted Next Frame Using Ground Truth Optical Flow
[image: Predicted Next Frame Using Ground Truth]

Difference between the above two
[image: Difference between the images]